# Visual Studio 2019 Change Viewing Browser

Tags: html, visual-studio, cross-browser, visual-studio-2019

My default browser is Chrome but I want to use Firefox Developer as my browser in Visual Studio 2019 Community edition on web pages I am working on.  The HTML menu has "View in browser (Google Chrome)" and I cannot find any option to change this.  Searched Microsoft and found nothing pertinent. Stackoverflow has only two related posts, one discusses toggling between Chrome and IE but couldn't see how they did it.

I expect this to be a head-slapper, but I'm stuck.  TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you have to do is download the firefox developer edition and set it as your default browser. Do this and if you have Visual Studio running, close it and reopen. It should be found under the IIS Express dropdown menu where you select the web browser. You may not have to have firefox dev edition set as your default browser but that is what I have running on my end and it works correctly.